# Baking ambient occlusion gives odd black vortex output?

Tags: texture-baking

I am having a very strange problem when I bake an Ambient Occlusion!

The problem is very very visible, When I click **Bake**, it bakes everything and then in the last few seconds it does this weird "vortex" kind of effect. It always starts from the bottom left.

Also, any UV unwrapping doesn't work either (UV unwrap, Smart uv project etc. all don't work).

[image]

Comment: That seems like a bug...

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend? It looks to me like you have overlapping UVs, which can cause this kind of "z-fighting"

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32335

password : lmg

Comment: Actually it's not a bug. The baking takes the wire material into account. In the baking options you should tick 'Normalized' (then materials are ignored for the baking), this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason this seems to be caused by the wire material.

If you remove it by pressing the **-** button:

[image]

Then it works as expected:

[image]

This looks like a bug to me. <s>You might want to consider reporting it to the [tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug).</s> I've since reported it [here](https://developer.blender.org/T42443).

---

Also note that there are some internal faces and non-manifold geometry in your model, which can also result in some artifacts. Try pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> in edit mode to select problem spots.

Comment: As I said in the comment to the question and in the bug tracker, you can actually just tick 'Normalized' in the bake options. This way materials are ignored when baking and it bakes just fine with a wire material.