# When I unwrap an object for texturing with custom seams, sometimes I get strange streaks while painting. How can I fix this?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

So I have a submarine that I've finished modelling, it is low-poly, and ready for texturing. The seams seem to work perfectly, and Blender has no complaints. The patterns lay out, and I start coloring in the areas in order to lay down the final textures on specific areas. Problem! Streaks start appearing outside the UV seams, across the entire texture. This started happening with Blender 2.71, and nothing I can do seems to fix them - there seems to be no rhyme to why they appear either:

[image]

Has anyone encountered this before? What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Oh yea , i have encountered this quiet a few times , it is either a bug or something like this : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/baking-ambient-occlusion-gives-odd-black-vortex-output

Comment: So it may be a bug. After extensive reworking of the UV's to remove specific areas and fix it again I did manage to produce a layout without the lines. With a little study, it seems to occur more often if there are intensive edge groupings.

Comment: well there you go